# Alter IIS 6 Home Directory permissions via PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-6

[image: Alter IIS 6 Home Directory permissions via PowerShell]

Does anyone know how can i alter the marked properties via powershell?
Just the class and property is enough :)

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Note: I did NOT write this blog, but it appears to answer the question:

```
<# This function will set the home directory of an IIS 6 website using Powershell 2 (it will not work with v1).
You need to pass it the site description (from the Web Site tab in IIS), the new path and the server your website is running on (this can be a machine name or an IP address).
You wouldn’t believe how long it took me to get this working. 
Found on: http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/change-the-home-directory-of-an-iis-6-website-using-powershell-2-and-wmi/

Usage: SetHomeDirectory "mysite.co.uk" "d:\websites\mysite" "myServer"
#>

Function SetHomeDirectory($SiteDescription, $NewPath, $serverName) {
    $query = "ServerComment = '" + $SiteDescription + "'"
    $webserver = Get-WMIObject -class IIsWebServerSetting -namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" -Filter $query -computer $serverName -authentication 6
    $nameQuery = "Name = '" + $webserver.Name + "/root'"
    $webdir = Get-WMIObject -class IIsWebVirtualDirSetting -namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" -Filter $nameQuery -computer $serverName -authentication 6
    $webdir.Path = $NewPath
    Set-WmiInstance -InputObject $webdir
}
```

Edit: Copied entire script with link as per comment